# create multiple entityManager from entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, entitymanager

When i used one entityManager for one entityManagerFactory everything work now i'm trying multiple EntityManager  for one entityManagerFactory

I have several scheme (Instance) of my database. With only 1 entityManagerFactory i'm trying to create multiple EntityManager witch pointe to different scheme:

entity Manager created like that

```
public static void addEntityManager( DataBase dataBaseClient, String idClient) {
    if (listEntityManager.containsKey(idClient))
        currentEntityManager = listEntityManager.get(idClient);

    else {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", dataBaseClient.getLogin());
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", dataBaseClient.getPassword());
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", dataBaseClient.getUrl());
        currentEntityManager = getEntityManagerFactoryMaster("efsm").createEntityManager(properties);
        listEntityManager.put(idClient, currentEntityManager);
    }

}
```

I have a variable that contain all
     static Map listEntityManager = new HashMap<>();

the problem when i try to request a database i get error that i haven"t when i use one entitymanager for one entitymanagerFactory, for example when i try to select all element from a table i get this error

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'fieldworke0_.fieldWorkerId' in 'field list'

How can i resolve this problem ?

Can i with only 1 entityManagerFactory create multiple EntityManager witch pointe to different scheme?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: For another schema you need another `EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for your response
Are you sure of that ? it is somewhere in the documentation ?

Comment: The persistence-unit defines the database, and hence the schema. The persistence-unit maps on to the EMF (evident from its constructor). Look at the JPA spec if needing confirmation ...

Comment: @Neil Stockton I'm not sure to understand, you say that EFM is like persistence-unit maps? so one EMF = persistence-unit maps so multiple persistence-unit?

Tell what can you suggest me to do to resolve this problem and do things dynamically Thanks

Comment: he is saying you need to create a new EntityManagerFactory with your different database credentials, as this different database represents different data.  Otherwise, JPA allows caching and a second level cache will cause havoc collecting entities from different datastores.  Some providers do allow connecting to different database at the EntityManager level, but it is provider specific, and I don't know how that works in Hibernate.  better to use a different EMF, and pass your database login properties to the EMF creation.

Comment: @chris

Thank you for your quick response, so i will create a EntityManagerFactory  for every EntityManager.

Comment: Creating emf for every em is antipattern as keeping single em during entire application life. Emf is heavy, long created object when Entitymanager is light, easy to create and not thread-safe. Best practice: one emf per schema during all application life, and new em for each unit of work (transaction or group of logically related transactions).